# Attribute Based Policy in keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

How to create a user attribute based policy?

```
var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var identity = context.getIdentity();
var attributes = identity.getAttributes();
if (identity.location=='mumbai') {
    $evaluation.grant();
}
```

A User has an attribute location and value as mumbai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could to some thing like this, as attributes are list, you can check first
element

```
var context = $evaluation.getContext();
var identity = context.getIdentity();
var attributes = identity.getAttributes();
if (attributes.location !== null && attributes.location[0] == "mumbai") {
    $evaluation.grant();
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to pass that param location from the spring boot application in application.properties?

Comment: why do you want to pass use attributes from resource server ?

Comment: Yes,I want to send the location from the database

Comment: You could use admin API https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.6/rest-api/index.html to update or though account service https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_account-service